# Import AI elements to Flash

Tags: flash, adobe-illustrator

I have a Adobe illustrator file which contains all design elements of my projects.

I am trying to import that file into flash, i am not able to import properly(design elements are getting disturbed).

So i have exported from AI to swf. How can I import this swf (contains all design elements) into my source file (Flash file) .This swf I tried to import into flash but design elements are not coming properly.

What is the proper way to import AI in Flash ?

Answer (score 1):

You might try this. Select all and then drag and drop (or copy and paste) into flash.
Then a dialogue window will come up and make sure the settings are correct (preserve layers and editing, etc.)

I have found this method to work better for some odd reason.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Under File->Export in AI, you could choose the SWF format, then use the drop down to export to "AI Layers to SWF Frames" or "AI Layers to SWF Symbols" - This *should* allow you to keep them organized as movieclips or sprites or whatever. The import usually isn't a totally seamless process and depends on what features you used in AI (drop shadows, kerning/leading don't come across so well, etc).

Comment: I tried this one, But things are not getting properly imported when i am trying to import this swf into Flash IDE.

Comment: most likely you're using techniques that aren't supported in Flash then - there are many. Take a look here and see if you see any red flags for your content: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flash/10.0_UsingFlash/WS8BE214F4-41C5-47f3-B0D5-7F3BCA41E1B7a.html